# Optimize download data from a Oracle database to a SQL Server database 2012 SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis

Recently, update the version of Oracle Database 11g R2 to. Before everything worked with 10g. I have some projects in SSIS and run data download is slower than before. I must also update the system connectors to the version of Oracle 11g R2 for data download is optimal?

Thank you for your help

Comment: We'd need a lot more information to do any sort of diagnosis.  My guess is that query plans have changed (though we'd need you to identify which queries are slower, what the old plans were, and what the new plans are to confirm).  That may be because of changes between the two versions of Oracle.  It may be because configuration changes were correctly or incorrectly made as part of the upgrade.  It may be some combination of factors.

Comment: Depends on the type of drivers you are using. You can use Attuinity driver for oracle or you can use the cozyroc drivers which help in bulk loads and are very fast. Depends on your circumstnaces.